# Reading MrSID (.sid) files with a GDAL built by vcpkg

Tags: gdal, c++, plugins, mrsid

I have built GDAL 3.7.0 with `vcpkg`, creating `..\Documents\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\lib\gdal.lib` (I make a `.lib` to statically link into my C++ application). It is my understanding that when `vcpkg` builds `gdal.lib` it links in static versions of the various driver code to read the various formats supported by GDAL. This corresponds to what I see in my application: It can open TIFF and JP2 files, even though there are no DLLs in the "plugins" directory that I provide to GDAL in the call `CPLSetConfigOption( "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH", "my/path/to/plugins" )`.

My understanding is that certain proprietary formats cannot be read by GDAL without some code provided by the format owner. I have downloaded the appropriate Windows DSDK from https://www.extensis.com/support/developers. Inside the SDK is the folder `lib`, which contains `lti_dsdk.lib`, `lti_dsdk_9.5.dll`, `lti_dsdk_cdll.lib`, `lti_dsdk_cdll_9.5.dll`, and `tbb.dll`. I have put all of these files in my `plugins` directory, run my program, and it still can't read `.sid` files.

I don't know if I need to provide the DSDK directory to `vcpkg` earlier in the process, during the GDAL build. I have looked at `vcpkg\ports\gdal\vcpkg.json` and it's not clear to me which feature/configuration I would use to specify the location of the DSDK.

Can you help me understand the specifics to enable `.sid` reading, either (a) the way I need to provide DLLs to my program at runtime, or (b) the way I need to build GDAL differently with `vcpkg`?

Comment: GDAL must be built with MrSID support, and in addition the MrSID binaries must be available. In GDAL it is possible to build drivers internally, or as plugins. So the plugin directory may be empty but a driver may still work. Usually proprietary drivers are built as plugins because then the end user may  activate and deactivate them easier.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others, here are the steps I took to use MrSID and ECW through GDAL:

(1a) Download the 32 bit Visual Studio 2022 DSDK from https://www.extensis.com/support/developers. Unzip it to C:\Users\michael.katz\Documents\vcpkg\sdk\MrSID_DSDK-9.5.5.5244-win32-vc17.

(1b) Go to https://supportsi.hexagon.com/help/s/article/ERDAS-ECW-JP2-SDK-Read-Only-Redistributable-download and download the appropriate SDK in the top-right corner. Unzip the download to C:\Users\michael.katz\Documents\vcpkg\sdk\ecw\Hexagon\ERDAS_ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK_5.5.0\Desktop_Read-Only.

(2) Edit C:\Users\michael.katz\Documents\vcpkg\triplets\x86-windows.cmake. (You can see the meaning of the flags at https://gdal.org/development/building_from_source.html.)

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x86)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)
set(ENV{CMAKE_WINDOWS_KITS_10_DIR} "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10")
set(VCPKG_CMAKE_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS "-DCMAKE_WINDOWS_KITS_10_DIR=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10\"")
set(VCPKG_ENV_PASSTHROUGH CMAKE_WINDOWS_KITS_10_DIR)

# CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR is the triplets directory
# such as C:/Users/michael.katz/Documents/vcpkg/triplets
message( STATUS "\n\n-----------------------CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR = ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}\n\n" )

if (PORT MATCHES "gdal")
    string(
        CONCAT x
        " \"-DMRSID_INCLUDE_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../sdk/MrSID_DSDK-9.5.5.5244-win32-vc17/Raster_DSDK/include\""
        " \"-DMRSID_LIBRARY=${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../sdk/MrSID_DSDK-9.5.5.5244-win32-vc17/Raster_DSDK/lib/lti_dsdk.lib\""
        " \"-DGDAL_USE_MRSID=ON\""
        " \"-DECW_INCLUDE_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../sdk/ecw/Hexagon/ERDAS_ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK_5.5.0/Desktop_Read-Only/include\""
        " \"-DECW_LIBRARY=${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../sdk/ecw/Hexagon/ERDAS_ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK_5.5.0/Desktop_Read-Only/lib/vc141/Win32/NCSEcw.lib\""
        " \"-DGDAL_USE_ECW=ON"
    )
    set(VCPKG_CMAKE_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS "${VCPKG_CMAKE_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS} ${x}" )
endif()

message( STATUS "\n\n-----------------------VCPKG_CMAKE_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS = ${VCPKG_CMAKE_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS}\n\n" )

message( STATUS "\n\n-----------------------FEATURES = ${FEATURES}\n\n" )

# message( STATUS "\n\n-----------------------VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS = ${VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS}\n\n" )
```

(3) Build gdal, but first remove the old gdal:

```
PS C:\Users\michael.katz\Documents\vcpkg> rmdir C:\Users\michael.katz.la\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives

PS C:\Users\michael.katz\Documents\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe remove gdal

PS C:\Users\michael.katz\Documents\vcpkg> rm C:\Users\michael.katz\Documents\vcpkg\buildtrees\gdal\x86-windows-rel\CMakeCache.txt

PS C:\Users\michael.katz\Documents\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe install gdal
```

(4a) Add `...MrSID_DSDK-9.5.5.5244-win32-vc17\Raster_DSDK\lib\lti_dsdk.lib` as a linker input for your project.

(4b) Add `...Desktop_Read-Only\lib\vc141\Win32\NCSEcw.lib` as a linker input for your project.

(5a) Copy `...MrSID_DSDK-9.5.5.5244-win32-vc17\Raster_DSDK\lib\lti_dsdk_9.5.dll` to the Release directory of your project, so it's a sibling to your `app.exe`.

(5b) Copy `...Desktop_Read-Only\redistributable\vc141\Win32\NCSEcw.dll` to the Release directory of your project, so it's a sibling to your `app.exe`.

(6) Rebuild your project.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem within a few days of you (but posted on stackoverflow instead of here), your fix with modifying the triplet didn't work for me, but I was able to modify the port and get it working.

Here's my answer in case anyone else runs into this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76766286/8177594